# WmiMonitorBrightness returns incorrect brightness value

Tags: windows, wmi, brightness

I am working on a Windows 10 .Net application that will allow users to set/adjust the system screen brightness. As part of this, I need to be able to query what the current system screen brightness is set to (what you would see if you opened Windows settings and navigated to System->Display to view the slider control that displays the current system brightness). To do both of these, update brightness and query brightness, I'm using the WMI WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods and WmiMonitorBrightness classes respectively.

Setting brightness using the WmiSetBrightness method of the WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods class seems to always work fine. However, querying the system brightness using the WmiMonitorBrightness class is where I'm having trouble. The problem is that when I use WmiSetBrightness to set the brightness to a specific value, I can see it work fine when confirming through the Windows OS UI, but when I query the change I just made using WmiMonitorBrightness, I randomly get an incorrect value.

For example, in my testing I use WmiSetBrightness to set brightness to 95. Then, when I query the current brightness using WmiMonitorBrightness it returns a brightness value of 93 (why would it return this unexpected value?). I also confirmed that WmiSetBrightness returns that there are 1-100 brightness levels on the machine, so setting brightness to 95 seems like it should work fine.

To include more information, this issue isn't something present in my .Net/C# code for querying brightness using WmiMonitorBrightness, it seems to be an issue with WmiMonitorBrightness itself. I say this because I can run commands in PowerShell using the same WMI classes to update and query brightness and the example scenario I described previously happens the same way. If I set brightness to 95 using WmiSetBrightness in PowerShell, querying the current brightness using WmiMonitorBrightness in PowerShell returns the incorrect value.

```
# Example of WmiMonitorBrightness that returns the incorrect/unexpected value
Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness
```

This also seems to be an issue only on certain machines. When I run these PowerShell commands on an HP laptop I have, the WmiMonitorBrightness query command has worked fine every time and returns the expected value. However, when I do this same thing on 2 different Surface Laptops I have (both running different Windows OS versions) it returns the unexpected/incorrect value.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why querying the current system brightness using WmiMonitorBrightness returns an unexpected value?